# Amazon AMI Windows instance + "user-data"?

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud

is it possible to send a "user-data" to the **Windows instance** at the loading? I know that amazon allow to send it to *nix-based instance, but I can't find any information for Windows.

Thanks for the help,
Cyril

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of a direct way about it. But, you can create a start-up script inside your instance, that will allow you reading user-data each time you reboot your system. Inside your user-data, you can configure what's going to run only once or every single time your instance loads.

Comment: That sounds great! How, exactly, does a script access the user data?

Comment: You can access user data with an HTTP GET (wget, curl, etc.)  See http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AESDG-chapter-instancedata.html

Answer (score 5):

Amazon updated EC2Config on Windows AMIs on April 11, 2012 to support scripting through user-data for batch scripts and in May 2012 to support powershell scripts.

```
<script></script> tags will create and execute a batch file.
<powershell></powershell> tags will create and execute a powershell script.
```

Note that by default it only runs at instance initialization, so if you want it to execute each time you boot, you have to run the EC2ConfigServiceSettings and tell it to allow this always.